# Using custom font located on a different server

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I have to use a custom font on one of the web pages. I am using @font-face in my CSS.

Now, I am not sure but I think for this to work the font should be on the same server as the web page. Is this right? I have tried using a different server but it didn't work. So, I am not sure if there was something I missed or a different server hosted font doesn't work.

If it works, then is it as simple as mentioning the complete URL in the url part of t @font-face? Or there is something more I need to do? What are the limitations? I know that in IE .eot fonts work.

Thanks.

Comment: I may be very wrong here but I think the font has to be in the client machine. Whether or not the server has it should be irrelevant since it's loaded by the browser, not the server side code, right?

Comment: @Renan : Not really.That's the reason why font-face was introduced. :-)

Comment: @harsha living and learning... I wish I could upvote your comment.

Comment: @PaulDixon : They work on other domains too.Please take a look at the fiddle link I posted in my answer below.

Comment: @Renan But I did upvote your comment.As they say,stay hungry,stay foolish :)

Comment: @harsha - in your sample, the i.nflcdn.com domain returns Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, which is the secret sauce which allows this to happen.

Comment: @harsha yeah I voted like that too, but I meant giving you rep :)

Comment: @Renan : I might not be completely right as well.As Paul here commented , Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers are necessary

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can use a font located on another server.

An Example

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: 'EndzoneSansLight';
    src: url('//:') format('no404'),
        url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/4.0/img/fonts/endzone-sans/light.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
        url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/4.0/img/fonts/endzone-sans/light.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/4.0/img/fonts/endzone-sans/light.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/4.0/img/fonts/endzone-sans/light.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PFVDM/)

Comment: Does it work on IE8 & below? I don't think so :(

Comment: @Leon : if the same server font-face works on IE8 or below , even this should

Comment: @Leon : Also , why do you need a font from another server?Won't it be possible  for you to upload the font to your server?

Comment: There are limitations with our product. It is hard to describe here but trust me, I can't.

Comment: @Leon : You don't have to explain in detail.If you could tell us a bit about the necessity of having the font to be included from another server,we could probably help you out better.

Comment: I just hit the same problem - I need to host icon font on a single location but be used on more than one domain. Rather than trying to have to remember to duplicate the file, we want to simply refer to a single source (less maintenance headache)

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about Google Fonts before ?

http://www.google.com/fonts/

That's the easiest way to import the custom font from other server (in this case Google's server) to your website.

choose your font and add this code on your web page

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Days+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And if I trace the url it will show this details

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Days One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Days One'), local('DaysOne-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/daysone/v3/yfpXiXt9Xp5H97keqlB0t_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah I have heard of google fonts but I think you can only use the fonts that they host. Can I upload my font on google fonts and use it?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry.. maybe at least for now. The last option is using image, but it will cost byte more to load